# ERROR 2020 (HY000): Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes, mysql error inside docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, nestjs

I got a react app with nest JS backend, I'm using MySQL as my database, I see a problem in my server when I'm trying to get a long-blob from the database.

I tried to recreate the actions of the server manually so I entered the MySQL docker container, and I ran into the same problem.

I have read a lot on this issue and from what I tried nothing works.
I have set the max_allowed_packet in the docker MySQL container to be at the maximum (1073741824), I checked the blob size by running this command :

[blob size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8AGB.png)

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(blob) FROM order WHERE id = 224;
```

The result was: 125881696.

When I ran:

```
SELECT blob FROM order WHERE id = 224;
```

I get the same error:

> ERROR 2020 (HY000): Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

[show max allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km4PH.png)

[query fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32W09.png)

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - ${IP}:8080:80
    links:
      - db:db

  db:
    image: mysql:latest # https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ - or mariadb https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
    ports:
      - ${IP}:3306:3306 # change ip if required
    command: [
      '--default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password',
      '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
      '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      '--max_allowed_packet=1024M',
      '--innodb-log-file-size=256M',
      '--net_buffer_length=256K'
    ]
    volumes:
      - ./wp-data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}"

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Does this work any better if you set max_allowed_packet to something smaller than 1024M? Try 512M. And maybe try spelling out the size 536870912 rather than using the M form. (And beware vast BLOBs; they can make your app slow down a lot, because your database is a bottleneck.)

Comment: Same results unfortunately @O.Jones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for that after long time searching!
In MySQL there is client-side configuration and server side configurations.
What I used until now was only server side setting and completly ignored client side settings.
In order to make your connection to MySQL to be able to have large amount of data be passed to client you need to use this command as you connection string to MySQL:

`mysql -p --max_allowed-packet=256M`

In that Way we can pass packets larger than the 64Mb(default values used by MySQL)